# How to group yara's results by file?

Tags: malware-detection

I'm trying to do some malware detection using yara

http://plusvic.github.io/yara/

The problem is i would like to group the results by file

the courrent commande line that I'm using is:

```
$ yara -r rules.yar malware_folder
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer since I've found it some where else 
enjoy

> $ for i in $(find e/ -type f); do echo -n "$i,"; IFS=$'\n' yara rules.yar "$i" | cut -d' ' -f1 | tr -t \n ,; echo; done > results.csv